# How to find missing quarter in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 1 table name input_table . In this table we have 3 columns . Date , quarter and name .the values inside this columns are like

```
Date    -- 22/07/1992 , 22/08/2022,   28/06/1991.  ...  
Quarter --   Q1 ,          Q2,           Q3,        Q4,
Name    --  Ram ,         shyam ,       pooja,     ...
```

Let suppose if for "Ram" he is missing Q4 for period 2022 . I want to figure out this only . That if any name is missing any quarter like Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4 any one of them , then in that case I should get that missing value in my result.

That if any name is missing any quarter like Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4 any one of them , then in that case I should get that missing value in my result.

Comment: We need better sample data.

Comment: besides your naming of the columns is not english, it would behelpful when you provide a [mre] with table, data and wanted result

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), sample data and desired output formats are described in #5 and #3 respectively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to select a name from the quarter and then you have to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses. I hope this query will be helpful:

```
SELECT name, quarter 
FROM input_table 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
```